# Using 「点」 vs 「所」 vs 「箇所」to refer to a point in a document, description, etc

Tags: grammar, words

When referring to previous document (manual, email, etc.) or a previous statement/reply I'm not sure of the difference between using 「点」, 「所」 and 「箇所」.

I would want to say something along the lines of:

> 「その点では、問題があります。」
>
> 「マニュアルには、一箇所は不一致になりました。」
>
> 「間違えたところは、４つあります。」

But to me, it seems as though 「点」, 「所」 and 「箇所」 are mainly interchangeable, granted the sentence might have to be slightly changed to accommodate the new word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**箇所{かしょ}** (or 個所) is a physical "point" you can point where it is (that is, on the paper or elsewhere). You can translate it as "place", "spot" or "site".
**点{てん}**, by contrast, indicates abstract "point" you can only name in your mind (unless it means literal "dot"). Possible translations are "respect", "regard" or "aspect".

> ○ 論旨{ろんし}に筋{すじ}の通{とお}らない**点**がある。 *There are illogicalities in the argument.*
> × 論旨に筋の通らない**箇所**がある。
>
> × 誤字{ごじ}を三**点**修正{しゅうせい}しました。
> ○ 誤字を三**箇所**修正しました。 *I fixed three typos.*

**所{ところ}** is a vague word more or less corresponds to "where". It could be used in place of both 箇所 and 点, just sounds more informal (colloquial) than them. Take care that 点 and 箇所 are counter words (as above), while 所 is *not* (`× 誤字を一ところ修正しました。`).

Comment: I'm sorry I had to downote. The reason is, we say 論旨に筋のお通らない箇所が有る。Please refer http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/158611/m0u/, 2, ウ, ところ is defined as same with 箇所, denoting the abstract point the size ( span ) of which is not specified. Thus we can use the word such as some kind of an quote quote "abstract noun".

Comment: I am sorry, while I should give my own answer, still let me advice. We can not say 点 and 箇所 are counter words. Source : http://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%82%B9-102028#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88,  0, 「7」. 点 also denotes the "quote quote" "abstract point".

Comment: (1) 論旨に筋の通らない箇所がある is definitely weird unless the 論旨 is really sounded out. Usually 論旨 is what you get from the uttered/written discussion, but itself doesn't have a form, I guess. (2) But ところ is also defined as 点 in the same line you've shown... (3) But your link tells that 点 *is* a  counter word (助数詞)...

Comment: Yes, this kind of "feeling dependent" stuff has nowhere to go, so let me end here. But if you watch for ex, the speeches by representitaves in the House sometimes says same stuff like, "総理のお書きになった文には不明な箇所（点）が御座います”。

Comment: That's because when you talk about someone's 文, it's almost always ambiguous which the letters/sounds (この文は日本語がおかしい) or content (この文は心を揺さぶる) you're mentioning. If the former, it's expected to be physically realized, but the latter is not.